# Is a there a simple solution to avoid problems with hotspots?

Tags: wifi, macos, keychain, tethering

It seems that `OSX` does not behave well with `hotspots`.

By `hotspot`, I mean the wireless networks which opens automatically a window for login/password such as

[image]

when you join them.

When you login for the first time to such a `hotspot`, there is no problem.

The problem occurs when to try connect later. I think `OSX` tries something like putting automatically your login/password, but it doesn't work. But the result is that the window to connect never shows up.

I had such a problem few months ago on `OSX 10.8` and it was difficult and unclear how to solve it. It involves `keychain` and other things.

It seems that this problem still exists on `OSX 10.9`.

So **is there an easy way to avoid these problems?**

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot it looks like your browser is opening (and later failing to open) a login screen in a new window. Try using a different browser.

You might also try

System Preferences -> Network -> [with "Wi-Fi" selected] Advanced ->
 uncheck "Remember networks this computer has joined"

and / or

Keychain Access -> [with "System" keychain selected] -> delete the AirPort network password

Comment: No, it's not the browser window. When you connect to such a network, `OSX` automatically opens this window.

Comment: I'm sure that you are in fact looking at some kind of browser window; check out the URL the bottom of your screenshot, "http://eduspot.inlalco.fr/login?......". You might also try deleting your cookies from your browsers.

Comment: Mac OS X has built-in functionality to detect hotspot redirects, and will automatically open a window to allow authentication (maybe just a Webkit view?). This is _not_ a part a browser, and as far as I know, there is no way to control this behavior.